# CMake: How to use an imported .so.1.2.3 in transitive dependencies

Tags: linux, cmake, shared-libraries

I have to import a libft4222.so.1.2.3 into a CMake project on Linux. There are no symlinks without version information like a plain libmyimportedlibrary.so. I am writing a `FindLibFT4222.cmake` to make the library usable in my project.

In my project, a shared library uses libft4222 like this:

```
if (LIBFT4222_FOUND)
    if (NOT TARGET LibFT4222::LibFT4222)
        add_library(LibFT4222::LibFT4222 UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
        set_target_properties(LibFT4222::LibFT4222
            PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LibFT4222_LIBS})
        target_include_directories(LibFT4222::LibFT4222
            INTERFACE
                ${LibFT4222_INCLUDE_DIR})
    endif()
endif()
```

`LibFT4222_LIBS` points to the imported location of the libft4222.so.1.2.3:

```
/path/to/libft4222.so.1.2.3
```

- I am adding this library as a dependency to a shared library A in my project.
- Finally, I have an executable depending on A.
- When I link the executable, the linker reports an error that it cannot find libft4222.so
- When I add libft4222 directly to the executable, it works.

The error message I get:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libft4222.so, needed by libSomeOtherLib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

How do I tell CMake to correctly handle libft4222.so.1.2.3 and not to omit .1.2.3?

Update 1: I looked at the SONAME property of libft4222.so.1.2.3:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -p libft4222.so.1.4.4.44  | grep SONAME
SONAME               libft4222.so
```

So I guess creating the symlinks is unavoidable.

Comment: "When I link the executable, CMake reports an error that it cannot find libft4222.so" - Most likely it is not CMake but a **linker** reports you that error. Could you add to the question post the **exact error message**?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, indeed. It's the linker. Clarified.

Comment: When run `ldd` for `libSomeOtherLib.so`, does it show `libft4222.so.1.2.3` or `libft4222.so` as the name of the linked library?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't have ldd for that architecture, but used objdump instead. It requires libft4222.so, probably because that's the soname of the imported .so.1.2.3.